# Trying to get the number of posts from authors with a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select the amount of articles each author has on my table.
Here's what I got so far:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_artigos as b WHERE a.id_autores = b.id_autores) as total
FROM tb_autores as a
GROUP BY
    total
ORDER BY
    total desc
```

I guess it wrong because it only return 19 rows and I have 24 authors. Another problem is that I need the id of each author and with the above query I only get the total value.

Anyone can help me with that please?

Edit: fixing sql code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, this would be done using an explicit `JOIN`.  However, a correlated subquery is fine.  The problem is your `GROUP BY` clause.  The correct `GROUP BY` is on the author id:

```
SELECT a.id_autores,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tb_artigos as b WHERE a.id_autores = b.id_autores) as total
FROM tb_autores a 
GROUP BY a.id_autores 
ORDER BY total desc;
```

I would suggest you compare the results of this query to your query and try to understand the difference between the two result sets (apart from the author id on each row).

Answer (score 1):

Some authors may not have any article which means you won't get anything out of a simple JOIN. Use this LEFT OUTER JOIN and the authors will be 24:

```
SELECT tb_autores.id_autores, COUNT(*)
FROM tb_autores
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tb_artigos
    ON tb_autores.id_autores = tb_artigos.id_autores
GROUP BY tb_autores.id_autores;
```

This is also the fastest and correct way to write that query.

Comment: As a note:  usually you don't want to use `count(*)` with `LEFT JOIN`.  I think you intend `COUNT(tb_artigos.id_autores)`.  And, lest anyone be confused, this is *not* the fastest way to write the query.  MySQL does a poor job optimizing aggregation queries.  The correlated query with proper indexes should have the best performance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have one line per article in the table, this is how I would      do it:

```
SELECT A.id_autores, B.nombre_autores, COUNT(*) FROM tb_artigos AS A
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tb_autores AS B ON A.id_autores=B.id_autores
GROUP BY A.id_autores, B.nombre_autores
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that my resolve your problem in single query with join instead of sub query.

```
SELECT a.id_autores, count( b.id_autores ) AS total FROM `tb_artigos` b, `tb_autores` a WHERE a.id_autores = b.id_autores GROUP BY b.id_autores ORDER BY total DESC
```

This will output like below:

```
id_autores      total
    77          4581
    106         166
    22          102
    2           81
    70          47
    38          25
    72          6
    71          4
    84          2
    1           2
```